# Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject->downloadAsString() uncaught error

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a PHP script that reads files from Cloud Storage. It works fine in local dev. But when it's run in App Engine standard environment, it outputs this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException in /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/RequestWrapper.php:362
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/RequestWrapper.php(206): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException))
#1 /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Storage/src/Connection/Rest.php(224): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#2 /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Storage/src/StorageObject.php(643): Google\Cloud\Storage\Connection\Rest->downloadObject(Array)
#3 /srv/vendor/google/cloud/Storage/src/StorageObject.php(574): Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject->downloadAsStream(Array)
#4 /srv/modules/profile/controllers/getresource.class.php(69): Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject->downloadAsString()
```

This doesn't happen to most of the files. The file causing this issue is about 250KB. I am wondering is there some kind of size limitation with downloadAsString()?

One of the files causing this issue is https://www.justjeans.com.au/wcsstore/JustJeansAuroraStorefrontAssetStore/css/main.css?timestamp=2019070295000

Comment: This error its related to a miss in your code hadling exceptions. Please provide some code to see how we can help you

Comment: $e->getMessage() return empty string.

Comment: Have you implemented a retry method in your code? Perhaps catching the exception and then retry the download of the offending files

Comment: The first step is to meet the StackOverflow's requirements to post a question. Review this link to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The `downloadAsString()` method downloads the file using stream, and then casts it to a string before returning it.

[Link to the SDK code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/StorageObject.php#L572-L575)

There should not be any issues with file sizes unless you are running out of memory in your PHP process.

Is there a file that causes the issue every time? If so, maybe adding that to the question would be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, there are a few files causing this issue. But other bigger files don't have this issue.

Comment: Doesn't look like a memory issue from the App Engine logs.